# Mp4 Video Container and the Codecs use with it

Tags: video, codec, mp4

I have started to learn about mp4 file format, and I just learned that mp4 is nothing but just a container that defines the structure of the video file, and that it has different codecs inside it for audio and video, as well as other data like metadata and subtitles.

I have been searching around for a while now but couldn't find so much on the basics of mp4 containers and the working and complete structure explanation of it.

So far I have read [this](http://www.videomaker.com/article/15362-video-formats-explained) and [this](http://www.dr-lex.be/info-stuff/mediaformats.html), but there is not enough information specifically about mp4 container.

My question is,

There are so many Audio/Video Codecs available which are used, but which Codecs are used with the mp4 container ?

Can we use any Codec with the mp4 container ? because there are like dozen different Codecs and how one would know which can be used with the mp4 container ?,

and is there a book or a paper on Mp4 container structure and explanation ?

Comment: Old question with a good new answer here: [Understanding containers and codecs](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/23264/3643)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4) on MPEG-4 is a great start as the MP4 file specification is part of the MPEG-4 spec.  Specifically version 2 of MP4 is [MPEG-4 Part 14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14). While not free, you can purchase copies of the ISO spec under [ISO# 14496-14:2003](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38538).  A preview with some detail is available from the ISO [here](http://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec14496-14%7Bed1.0%7Den.pdf).

It is designed to contain any of the various MPEG video formats, including MPEG, MPEG-2, MPEG-4 Part 2 (generic MPEG-4) and, probably most commonly, MPEG-4 part 10 (H.264).  It can theoretically support almost any format of video stream, however those 4 are the most widely supported for the file type.

The full list of officially registered codec types is available from the MP4 Registration Authority [here](http://mp4ra.org/codecs.html).

Comment: Can't any container theoretically support any codec? Isn't this just a matter of the player being able to understand the two correctly?

Comment: @digivisionmedia depends on the container.  Some may have enumerations of allowed codecs as use an int to identify it rather than an open entry.  You could theoretically make a container that can hold any codec though.